# Max From Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Create proc [dbo].[SpGetPharmacyLogpast]
AS
SELECT  Pharmacylog.PharmcyItemID,Pharmacylog.PastQuantity,Pharmacylog.NowQuantity,Pharmacylog.Amount,Pharmacylog.TotalValue,PharmacyItems.ID  from Pharmacylog
LEFT JOIN PharmacyItems
ON  PharmacyItems.ID=Pharmacylog.PharmcyItemID where PharmacyItems.ItemID=8

RETURN
```

I need to get Max of this select based on Pharmacylog.pharmacyItemID

Comment: what does "Max of this select" means?, max what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @lamak question.

but wild guess:

```
Create proc [dbo].[SpGetPharmacyLogpast]
AS
SELECT  TOP 1 Pharmacylog.PharmcyItemID,Pharmacylog.PastQuantity,Pharmacylog.NowQuantity,Pharmacylog.Amount,Pharmacylog.TotalValue,PharmacyItems.ID  
from Pharmacylog 
LEFT JOIN PharmacyItems
ON  PharmacyItems.ID=Pharmacylog.PharmcyItemID 
where PharmacyItems.ItemID=8
ORDER BY Pharmacylog.PharmcyItemID DESC 
RETURN
```